# How to send extra data (such as a UID) as part of paypal express checkout?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am a noob to paypal SDK, so bear with me. I have gotten paypal payments working through the sandbox, got the IPN to fire and email me back with response. So far so good.

I am using the sample code for basic integration from the paypal site (this is the payment snippet)

```
   payment: function() {

                                            var env    = this.props.env;
                                            var client = this.props.client;

                                            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                                                transactions: [
                                                    {
                                                        amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
//what do I put here to pass a custom var called uid?

                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            });
                                        },
```

My Question is this: How to I pass an extra parameter (apart from the current **amount: { etc** currently passed?  I have a UID I generate which I would like to pass as a paramter and then later grab with _POST in my IPN listener in order to validate the entry in my database based on this value. But for the life of me I can't find any examples of how to pass params apart from the above example . Any help here would be much appreciated and lauded :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `custom` field from these docs:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/

```
transactions: [
    {
        amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' },
        custom: 'xxxxxxx'       
    }
]
```

Comment: right, (and again, I apologize for my "noobness" but how do I pass that "custom" parameter in the context of the sample code above?  I have a uid I am generating in php and then adding as a hidden "form" value which I then pull in via   var uid = document.forms["iiform"].elements["uid"].value;  ... but the syntax of how to add that to the transactions: [   arg escapes me.

Comment: Added an example to my answer

Comment: thanks SO much, that worked. One last question (and I hate to ask but like I say this is my first dip of the toe into web stuff coming from a game dev background :) ) I have a var called uid I generate. How do I pass that as custom: instead of 'xxxxxx'. Javascript is new to me as is JSON but I need to get this working asap. I tried custom: uid   but that caused an error that stopped my button from working.

Comment: Yeah it should just be `custom: uid`. What error did you get? Are you creating the `uid` variable nearby to where you're trying to use it?

Comment: actually my bad. typo misname. Working awesome now. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem! For future reference you might get a faster answer asking a question over at our repo -- https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues

Comment: i am able to send custom field to paypal. but after payment how do i read the response(specially the custom value i send to paypal)
here is my code:
custom: '88888' //i pass custom value to pyapal
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    }
i need to know details.??? to read custom field.

Comment: Does this work? I did not try out yet.